# Why I can not install plugins Compute engine instance? HTTP ERROR 401 Unauthorized

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

I created GCP VM instance and I can SSH.

```
miki@devsecops-cloud:~/kubernetes-devops-security/setup/jenkins-plugins$ ls -la
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 miki miki 4096 Sep 20 10:36 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 miki miki 4096 Sep 20 10:36 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki 1100 Sep 20 10:36 plugin-installer.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki  171 Sep 20 10:36 plugins.txt
```

Now the next step is to install Jenkins plugins from bash script.
Well it does not work at all.
I go this error

```
sudo bash plugin-installer.sh 
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
http://localhost:8080


........Installing performance@3.18 ..
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401 Unauthorized</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/pluginManager/installNecessaryPlugins</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>401</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Unauthorized</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>Stapler</td></tr>
</table>
<hr/><a href="https://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 10.0.11</a><hr/>
```

may be problem is that I pointed to credentials at host machine

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/miki/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
```

On the host,account list

```
gcloud auth list
       Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       johnholmes@gmail.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT
```

On the VM

```
gcloud auth list
                  Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       931909916149-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

On VM I tried to login

```
gcloud auth login
Your credentials may be visible to others with access to this
virtual machine. Are you sure you want to authenticate with
your personal account?

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Go to the following link in your browser:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=32312940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsdk.cloud.google.com%2Fauthcode.html&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fsqlservice.login+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Faccounts.reauth&state=emNPFQkW7AHLJG97s6QGUqRSvvpCVV&prompt=consent&access_type=offline&code_challenge=LtH3n7LWTG8SZfOBT8jKZTrkb-fWECYekLVKNn2REBo&code_challenge_method=S256

Enter authorization code: 4/0ARtbsJrLZR41bqLkT2--0J9vOllonBoA2NU2l7NcI7nMGD0nbjFiRFSRkj2Cr7mjlADhHw

You are now logged in as [johnholmes@gmail.com].
```

But same problems are still here,401 error.

How to setup a proper credentials on VM machine?

Comment: just a wild guess: maybe plugin-installer.sh calls some GCP APIs for which neither your user account (johnholmes@gmail.com), nor your default Compute Engine service account (931909916149-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com) have sufficient IAM permissions? Does you service account have the IAM bindings mentioned here? https://cloud.google.com/architecture/using-jenkins-for-distributed-builds-on-compute-engine#configure_cloud_identity_and_access_management

Comment: @jackdbd In this case I must create jenkins user on my VM?

Comment: I don't know if you need to create a Jenkins user (I've used, but never configured Jenkins). In order to use any GCP resource, such as a Compute Engine VM, you need an "automated user". That user is called service account (SA). A SA can be attached to the GCP resource (the VM) and has the IAM permissions you gave it. The reason the guide creates this SA is becuse is good practice to enforce a least privilege principle and give a SA only the IAM permissions it actually needs to perform its job.

Comment: @jackdbd I folloed alll the steps,jenkins                                 jenkins@zuhaibraja76.iam.gserviceaccount.com        False
was added

Comment: You can use the default Compute Engine SA (931909916149-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com in your case) and attach it to the VM which runs Jenkins. But if you always use the default Compute Engine SA for everything you end up with a SA which has too many IAM permissions and you soon lose track of which one it really needs.